# How can I import my own package in python?

Tags: python

I have a project

```
testci/
├── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mylib.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── pow_test.py
```

When I run `python3.6 test/pow_test.py` I see an error:

> File "test/pow_test.py", line 3, in 
> import testci.src.mylib as mylib
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testci'

**pow_test.py**

```
from testci.src.mylib import get_abs


def test_abs():
    assert get_abs(-10) == 10
```

How can I fix this error?

System details: Ububntu 16.04 LTS, Python 3.6.10

Comment: The module has to be in your path, this is fundamentally how it works for any module.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from  .src import  mylib
from mylib import get_abs
```

if it won't work then import one by one. But don't import the root folder since the file you are importing to is on the same folder you are trying to import then it will always raise an error

Answer (score 0):

Run Python with the `-m` argument within the base `testsci` package to execute as a submodule.

I made a similar mock folder structure:

```
├───abc_blah
│   │   abc_blah.py
│   │   __init__.py
│
└───def
    │   def.py
    │   __init__.py
```

abc_blah.py

```
print('abc')
```

def.py

```
import abc_blah.abc_blah
```

Execute like such:

```
python -m def.def
```

Correctly prints out 'abc' as expected here.

Answer (score 0):

simply add `__package__ = "testci"` and also it is a good practice to add a `try and except` block

Your final code should look something like

```py
try:
    from testci.src.mylib import get_abs
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from ..testci.src.mylib import get_abs
```

for running it, type `python -m test.pow_test`

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is how the package is installed. The import looks fine to me. As it says CI I'm guessing you're having the package installed remotely with only the test folder somehow.

Try adding a `setup.py` file where you define that both the `test` as well as the `src` packages are part of your `testci` package.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to organize a project, keep things consider in mind, structure should be simple and more scaleable, can differentiate the things in codebase easily.

one of the few good possible ways to structure a project is below

```
project/
├── app.py
├── dockerfile
├── pipfile
├── Readme.md
├── requiements.txt
├── src_code
│   ├── code
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mylib.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_func.py
└── travisfile
```

here `app.py` is main file which is responsible to run your entire project